# Trying to nest a SUM(FILTER inside a SUMIFS function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

New to the wonderful world of excel formulas and hoping someone has a solution to the below:

I am trying to use SUM/FILTER functions inside a SUMIF function to return results filtered by the column in the filter section as well as those matching a specific date in a date column

This is a formula that will be used across multiple reports so it's important to be able to filter by the column header

[image: Sample of data]

The =SUM(FILTER part of this formula works fine and returns the total value of the column

However when I try to add this to a SUMIFS Function and further filter the data so that only the total from results matching the date are returned

The current formula that works to return the total of the "Amount Spent" Column is `=SUM(FILTER(A2:F393, A1:F1="Amount Spent"))`

What I want to add this to is a SUMIFS so that the "Day" column is also searched to return the exact day

```
=SUMIFS(A2:F393, SUM(FILTER(A2:F393, A1:F1="Amount Spent"))
```

Similarly if I remove the FILTER/SUM
`=SUMIFS(A:F, A1:F1,"Amount Spent", A:A, A2)` I get a #VALUE error message

Comment: Hi Welcome To SO. Please post your sample data using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** and include your expected output. Just for reference, if I have understood correctly, arrays dont work with `SUMIFS()` criteria range parameters. **[SUMIFS()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)** syntax starts with the param `range`.

Comment: Hi @MayukhBhattacharya thanks for the comment yes I essentially want to do the following:

Total from "amount spent" column if the data is within a row that matches a specific date in the "day" Column. eg 02/10/2023

The formula needs to also be able to filter the data based on header titles, so if I wanted to get results for say, "impressions" it would be easy to implement

Comment: Posted using `SUMIFS()` and one more variant using `FILTER()` with `TOCOL()`

Comment: I don't know how, but I know that quite a lot of `SumIF()` or `SumIFS()` use cases can also be handled with the `SumProduct()` function.

Answer (score 0):

To use `FILTER` on both rows and columns, first `FILTER` by the columns, then `FILTER` that result by the rows:

```
=SUM(FILTER(FILTER($A$1:$F$12,($A$1:$F$1="Amount")),$A$1:$A$12=DATE(2023,10,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kevin. When I use the formula above I get #CALC error though?

Comment: Notice I've changed the heading "Amount" because I've had to recreate your data. Make sure you are using the heading name that suits your data. Also I've assumed your "day" column is a date. If it is text you might have to use something like `$A$1:$A$12="2/10/2023"`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try something along the lines of using `TOCOL()` with `FILTER()`

[image]

---

```
=SUM(FILTER(TOCOL(A2:F13/(I1=A1:F1),2),A2:A13=DATE(2023,10,2)))
```

---

Or, Using `SUMIFS()`

[image]

---

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(A2:F13,,MATCH(I1,A1:F1,0)),A2:A13,DATE(2023,10,2))
```

---